# Subscript before a function symbol?

Tags: functions, notation, computer-science, game-theory

Does anyone know what the subscript before the function means?
$$
_pf_p
$$

It's part of a definition for selfish routing in networks:

Let $N = (V,E)$ be the network, which is a directed graph. There are $k$ source-destination paris $\{{s_1}, {t_1}\}, ..., \{{s_k}, {t_k}\}$. ${P_i}$ = the set of paths from ${s_i}$ to ${t_i}$ and $P = \cup_iP_i$. The flow $f: P \rightarrow R^+$, where $P$ is negligible traffic and $R^+$ represents a flow. The load of edge $e$ is $f_e = \sum_{p\in P}$ such that $e$ is in $_pf_p$.

Also, am I right in thinking this means the union of all possible paths?
$$P = \cup_iP_i$$

Thanks!

Comment: should this be migrated to [cs.se]. I might be wrong.

Comment: This is not a standard notation. Where did you see it? The book or article should explain what the notation means. @Sabyasachi It could be a [cs.se] question, except that since this isn't a standard notation, we can't help much more than here. CS would be a better place than here to come up with a correct defintion of the load of an edge.

Comment: @Gilles so should it be migrated or not?

Comment: @Sabyasachi The question can be migrated, but: tearfulheart, you should say where you found this definition.

Comment: @Gilles I found this in my lecture handouts, but I now think it may just be some notation inconsistency on the author's part, "$_{p∈P}$ such that $e$ is in $p$" should be in subscript too. So it should read:  The load of edge $e$ is $f_e = \sum _{p∈P such that  e  is  in  p}f_p$.

Comment: @tearfulheart I think your interpretation is absolutely correct, at least in the context you have presented. And I also think you can just copy your previous comment to an answer and accept it yourself.

Comment: (If you chose to follow my advice above, use the following code for the "correct" typesetting: `$f_e = \sum_{p\in P \text{ such that }e\text{ is in }p} f_p$`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The load of edge $e$ is $f_e = \sum_{p\in P}$ such that $e$ is in $_pf_p$" should be:  $$f_e = \sum_{p\in P \text{ such that }e\text{ is in }p} f_p$$